# Empty a Select Box with YUI 2

Tags: javascript, yui

If you have a select box that looks like this:

`<select id="test"></select>`

You could empty it with jQuery like this:

```
$('#test').empty();
```

How could I do something like this using YUI 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea how you would do this with YUI 2 but here's how you could do it with plain javascript:

```
document.getElementById('test').length = 0;
```